# Create SQL tables for each user as security measure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've research this topic and I'm relatively sure in most practices the answer is "No", but I would like some second opinions specific to my case.

We're currently working on a multi user web-app where each user will basically have there own copy "portal/app" within the web-app. It's not performance I'm worried about, but security.

I'm considering partitioning the data with a prefix userid_table1, userid_table2 to make it more manageable and ensure no security validation oversight is made by the team in development as we can easily add a validation to ensure that queries can only be run against tables with userid_*.

Would you still recommend against this method ?

Comment: Don't do it, it would cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Look at [SQL Server Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: As you already stated, the answer HAS to be no. It's bad in many ways. If you want security for like passwords, just use hash function and maybe salt. In general try to break your huge security problem to little easier ones.

Comment: Hmm, depends on the details of the use case... But at least use different schemas or databases not prefixes in the identifiers.

Comment: Consider your bank is probably concerned about security too. Do you think they create separate tables for your account and transactions?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm considering partitioning the data with a prefix userid_table1, userid_table2 to make it more manageable and ensure no security validation oversight is made by the team in development as we can easily add a validation to ensure that queries can only be run against tables with userid_*.

More manageable?  That sounds like a joke.  Your database will end up with a zillion different tables.  *Any* operation that you want to do across all users will be a nightmare:

- Declaring foreign key constraints.
- Defining a new index on the tables.
- Adding a new column.
- Restructuring the tables.
- And so on.  And so on.

Your *users* may be limited to a single table.  But the application developer and DBA need to deal with all of them.  I cringe thinking about trying to figure out where performance bottlenecks are in such a system.

I should add that databases are optimized for *big* tables not lots of tables, so multiple tables are typically less efficient.  And even less efficient when you think about all the half-filled pages in all those tables.

The same entities should not be spread among multiple tables, unless you have a really, really good reason.  This is not a really good reason.  One simple solution is to prevent users from having access to the base tables.  Just give them access to views or user-defined table functions -- and have all of these filter on user ids.

There are some edge cases where you do want separate tables for each user.  Typically, each user would have a very complex tables (think B2B application) and, in fact, they might have their own database.  There may also be legal requirements to separate data.  In these cases, though, the "separateness" would typically be at the *database* level, not the *table* level.

Comment: Thanks for a well formulated answer and I think using only views and preventing access to base tables sounds like an elegant solution.